How to run a command at the same time with the running the application in Flask?
I have a script as a flask command and I want to run it when the system starts until the system ends. It should be a thread basically. I already created the command and it is working fine. How can I run it at the same time with the system?
flask_commands.py:
@click.command()
def file_watcher() -> None:
    context.interactor_type = 'flask command'

    event_handler = Handler()
    folder_path = core.settings['folder_path']
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_path, recursive=True)

    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()

file_watcher.py
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        logging.log(logging.INFO, f'New file created: {event.src_path}')
        print(f'New file created: {event.src_path}')
        ...
        print(datamodel)

app.py
from ...


app = create_app("pb")

init_flask_cmds(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = core.settings.get('listening_port', 5000)
    app.run(
        debug=True,
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=port
    )

I'm running the application like this: flask run

You could use the threading library and something like this in your app.py
import threading
from ...
from flask_commands import file_watcher

app = create_app("pb")

init_flask_cmds(app)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = core.settings.get('listening_port', 5000)
    file_watcher_thread = threading.Thread(target=file_watcher, daemon=True)
    file_watcher_thread.run()
    app.run(
        debug=True,
        host="0.0.0.0",
        port=port
    )
    file_watcher_thread.join(1)

If on Linux, you can also use the signaling library to send the Keyboard interrupt to the thread and make it terminate, on Windows signaling might make problems. But if you don't intend to use the function as a standalone you could also implement a threading.Event to terminate the thread, as is shown here
Another good way could be to add the cleanup to the teardown context of the flask application. You use this function to register a method that runs when the app context is destroyed to make sure your thread is stopped. But I've never done that myself.
